# failed to load objects at console through angular js controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created an service eliteApi

```
(function () {
    'use strict'
    angular.module('eliteApp').factory('eliteApi',  [eliteApi]);
    function eliteApi() {
        var leagues = JSON.parse('[{"id":1005,"name":"5th Grade Saturday 2013-14-5"}]');
        var leagueData = JSON.parse('{"league":{"name":"Spring Fling Tournament 2014","id":2009}}');
        function getLeagues() {
            return leagues;
        }
        function getLeaguesData() {
            return leagueData;
        }
        return {
            getLeagues: getLeagues,
            getLeaguesData: getLeaguesData,
        };   
    };
})();
```

then I've created a new controller leaguesCtrl with injection to service eliteApi:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('eliteApp').controller('leaguesCtrl', ['eliteApi', leaguesCtrl]);
    function leaguesCtrl(eliteApi) {
        var vm = this;
        var leagues = eliteApi.getLeagues();
        var leagueData = eliteApi.getLeagueData();
        console.log(leagues, leagueData);
    };
})();
```

and I related this controller to my html file in order to test it :

```
<ion-nav-view ng-controller="leaguesCtrl">
    <ion-content class="has-header">
        <h1>Leagues</h1>
    </ion-content>
</ion-nav-view>
```

but my console didn't gave any object so what's wrong with my code, I didn't figure it out if u can help me please?

Comment: you said that you created an service eliteApi but you wrote as a controller?

Comment: sorry I meant a controller eliteApi, m tracking a tutorial he got object details at the console, but I didn't get any thing I don't knw why

Comment: I fix it with .factory but the same result no object details

Comment: Could it be that in the object you're returning in the service you have an extra comma?

Comment: no its not the comma

Answer (score 0):

First create a service as eliteApi

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('eliteApp').factory('eliteApi', ['$http',"$q","$ionicLoading",eliteApi]);

    function eliteApi($http, $q,$ionicLoading)
    {
        var currentLeagueId;

        function getLeagues() {
            // return leagues;

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get("app/data.json").success(function(data){

                deferred.resolve(data);
            })

            .error(function(){
                console.log("error while making http calls");
                deferred.reject();
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        function setLeagueId(leagueId)
        {


            currentLeagueId = leagueId; 

        }

        function getLeagueData() {
            // return leagueData;

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $ionicLoading.show({template:"Loading....."});

            var main = $http.get("app/data.json" + currentLeagueId).success(function(data,status) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log("Recived Schedule data via HTTP", data,status);
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(){
                console.log("error while making http calls");
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                deferred.reject();
            }); 
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        return {
            getLeagues: getLeagues,
            getLeagueData: getLeagueData,
            setLeagueId: setLeagueId

        };
    };

})();
```

Create your LeaguesCtrl as

```
(function  () {
    angular.module("eliteApp").controller('LeaguesCtrl', ['$scope', '$state','eliteApi', LeaguesCtrl]);

    function LeaguesCtrl($scope, $state,eliteApi) {
        var vm = this;
        eliteApi.getLeagues().then(function (data) 
        {
            console.log("Data in LeaguesCtrl");
            console.log(data);
            $scope.leagues = data;
            console.log($scope.leagues);
            $scope.test = "Test message"
        });
        // var leagueData = eliteApi.getLeagueData();

        // console.log(leagues, leagueData);




        vm.selectLeague = function(id){
            console.log(id);
            eliteApi.setLeagueId(id);

            $state.go("app.teams");

        }

    };
})();
```

and create a  app/data.json file in your project as

```
{"league":{"name":"Laker Challenge 2014","id":2019,"homeScreen":"###Select one of the tabs above for various info, such as Team Schedule, Rules, Full Tournament Schedule, Standings, Direction, etc.###\n\n<br/>**Championship participants will be calculated throughout the tournament and posted below, on this page.  A hard copy will also be posted at each site and updated throughout the day Sunday. Be sure to press the refresh button on your device to ensure you are getting the most current updates.**  \n\n###Championship Games###\n\n<br/>**5th Grade Championship Game. Sunday, 4PM, court 1**\n<br>1st Place  **Team TBD  vs**      2nd Place **Team TBD**\n<br/> **5th Grade Champions:   Winner  -  Score **\n\n<br/>**6th Grade Championship Game.  Sunday, 4PM court 2**\n<br>1st Place:  **Elite Coalition  vs**      2nd Place **HC Elite - 6th**\n<br/>**6th Grade Champions: Elite Coaclition:  48  -  32**\n\n<br/>**6th-7th Grade Championship Game.  Sunday, 3PM, court 1**\n<br>1st Place   **Ravens 6th  vs**      2nd Place **HC Elite - 6th** \n<br/> **6th-7th Grade Champions:  Ravens 6th  -  54 - 46**\n\n<br/>**8th Grade White Championship Game.  Sunday, 3PM court 3**\n<br>1st Place   **HC Elite 7th  vs**      2nd Place **Ravens - 8th Etchison** \n<br/> **8th Grade Champions:  Ravens 8th - Etchison** \n\n<br/>**8th Grade Red Playoffs.:  Sunday:  Semi Finals 1PM and Championship at 3PM**\n<br>Semi Final  1, Sunday, 12pm, ct 2:  1st Place   **Team TBD  vs**      4th Place **Team TBD** \n<br>Semi Final  2, Sunday, 12pm, ct 3:  2nd Place   **Team TBD  vs**      3rd Place **Team TBD** \n<br>2pm:   **MD 3D  vs**      Winner Semi 2 **HC Elite 8th - PHillips** \n<br/> **8th Grade Red Champions:  HC Elite 8th - Phillips** \n\n\n","rulesScreen":"**HS Federation rules except where noted.**\n\t\t\t\t\t\n- Two 45 second timeouts per half -   T/Os don’t carry-over from 1st half to 2nd half.  \n- 20 minute halves.  Clock stops on all whistles the last 1 minute of first half and last 2 minutes of 2nd half.   \n- No pressing or half-court trapping after lead reaches 15 pts (5th and younger) 20 pts (6th and Older). \n- 2 behavior related technical fouls in the same game or any ejection will result in removal from current ,and next game as well as any other remaining games that day.\n- No technical fouls for book errors.  Just correct the mistake and move on.\n- Teams can start game with 4 players.  If you have 4 players available at game time, the game must start.\n- No dunking at sites where \"No Dunking\" is posted on the backboards. \n\n- Overtime* –One 2 minute OT.  One timeout per team in OT.\n-If still tied after One OT, Penalty Shoot-out (Soccer Style):\n•\tCoach Selects Order of 5 shooters, MUST be the players on court at end of OT.\n•\tAlternate Shooting ONE Free Throw, Best of 5 Shooters.\n•\tIF tied after 5 shooters repeat in same order until one team makes a shot and one misses a shot.\n*Championship Game: One 3-minute overtime. If still tied after one OT, consecutive 2 minute OT’s until there is a winner\n\n<br/>The following will be used to determine top two teams for the Championship game:\n<br/>- Overall Record (Wins vs. Losses)\n<br/>-- Head to Head (For 2-way tie or 3-way tie if one team beat other two)\n<br/>- Record vs Teams tied. \n<br/>- Point Differential vs Teams tied\n<br/>- Overall Point Differential \n<br/>- Coin Flip\n<br/>*In age groups with multiple divisions, the top team from each division will advance based on the above criteria*\n"},"teams":[{"divisionName":" 5th","divisionTeams":[{"id":5669,"name":"HCYP Sharks - Blue 5th","coach":"Anthony Tookes"},{"id":5666,"name":"HYCP Sharks - Red  5th","coach":"Anthony Tookes"},{"id":5667,"name":"MADE Elite -4th","coach":"Mark Alarie"},{"id":5676,"name":"Reisterstown Wolfpack 5th","coach":"Stephen Goldstein "},{"id":5668,"name":"Sharks - 4th","coach":"Frank Minni"}]},{"divisionName":" 6-7th","divisionTeams":[{"id":5672,"name":"Baltimore Supreme  6th","coach":"James Batchelor"},{"id":5670,"name":"Columbia Ravens  6th","coach":"John Miller"},{"id":5674,"name":"E-City Ballers - 7th","coach":"Jonathan Harris"},{"id":5671,"name":"HC Elite Green 6th","coach":"James Stefan"},{"id":5673,"name":"MADE Elite  6th","coach":"Josh Figueroa"}]},{"divisionName":" 6th","divisionTeams":[{"id":5677,"name":"Elite Coalition  6th","coach":"Tony Hamlin"},{"id":5681,"name":"Force Attack 6th","coach":"randy henggeler"},{"id":5675,"name":"HC Elite White 6th","coach":"Eddie OMalley"},{"id":5679,"name":"MADE Elite - 5th","coach":"Carl Travis"},{"id":5678,"name":"Savage Eagles  6th","coach":"Mike Hewitt"}]},{"divisionName":"8th Red","divisionTeams":[{"id":5685,"name":"HC Elite - Phillips  8th","coach":"Bill Phillips"},{"id":5686,"name":"Maryland 3D Gold  8th","coach":"Erik"},{"id":5682,"name":"MD Playmakers Red - 8th","coach":"Doug Clayton"},{"id":5689,"name":"Ravens  Cook  8th","coach":"John Cook"}]},{"divisionName":"8th White","divisionTeams":[{"id":5688,"name":"Glenwood  8th","coach":"Bob Trawick"},{"id":5687,"name":"HC Elite - 7th","coach":"Steve Michelotti"},{"id":5683,"name":"Maryland 3D  8th","coach":"Erik Larson"},{"id":5680,"name":"Maryland 3D Red 8th","coach":"Erik Larson"},{"id":5684,"name":"Ravens - Etchison  8th","coach":"Carl"}]},{"divisionName":"Sunday Championships","divisionTeams":[{"id":5704,"name":"5th Grade 1st Seed","coach":""},{"id":5708,"name":"5th Grade 2nd Seed","coach":""},{"id":5706,"name":"6-7th Grade 1st Seed","coach":""},{"id":5710,"name":"6-7th Grade 2nd Seed","coach":""},{"id":5705,"name":"6th Grade 1st Seed","coach":""},{"id":5709,"name":"6th Grade 2nd Seed","coach":""},{"id":5707,"name":"8th Grade White 1st Seed","coach":""},{"id":5711,"name":"8th Grade White 2nd Seed","coach":""},{"id":5698,"name":"8th Red  1st Seed","coach":""},{"id":5699,"name":"8th Red - 2nd Seed","coach":""},{"id":5700,"name":"8th Red - 3rd Seed","coach":""},{"id":5701,"name":"8th Red - 4th Seed","coach":""},{"id":5702,"name":"8th Red - Semi Final 1 winner","coach":""},{"id":5703,"name":"8th Red - Semi Final 2 winner","coach":""}]}],"locations":[{"id":1021,"name":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","address":"822 W Lake Ave, Baltimore, MD 21210","latitude":39.370000,"longitude":-76.630000},{"id":1022,"name":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","address":"822 W Lake Ave, Baltimore, MD 21210","latitude":39.370000,"longitude":-76.630000},{"id":1023,"name":"Boys Latin School ct 3","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","address":"822 W Lake Ave, Baltimore, MD 21210","latitude":39.370000,"longitude":-76.630000},{"id":1024,"name":"Boys Latin School ct 4","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","address":"822 W Lake Ave, Baltimore, MD 21210","latitude":39.370000,"longitude":-76.630000}],"games":[{"id":8437,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"HYCP Sharks - Red  5th","team1Id":5666,"team2":"Sharks - 4th","team2Id":5668,"team1Score":"43","team2Score":"9","time":"2014-11-15T08:00:00"},{"id":8460,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"HCYP Sharks - Blue 5th","team1Id":5669,"team2":"Reisterstown Wolfpack 5th","team2Id":5676,"team1Score":"19","team2Score":"29","time":"2014-11-15T08:00:00"},{"id":8474,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"Maryland 3D Red 8th","team1Id":5680,"team2":"HC Elite - 7th","team2Id":5687,"team1Score":"42","team2Score":"20","time":"2014-11-15T09:00:00"},{"id":8443,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"MADE Elite -4th","team1Id":5667,"team2":"Reisterstown Wolfpack 5th","team2Id":5676,"team1Score":"31","team2Score":"17","time":"2014-11-15T10:00:00"},{"id":8446,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"HCYP Sharks - Blue 5th","team1Id":5669,"team2":"Sharks - 4th","team2Id":5668,"team1Score":"29","team2Score":"10","time":"2014-11-15T10:00:00"},{"id":8441,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"Ravens  Cook  8th","team1Id":5689,"team2":"MD Playmakers Red - 8th","team2Id":5682,"team1Score":"51","team2Score":"36","time":"2014-11-15T11:00:00"},{"id":8442,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"HC Elite White 6th","team1Id":5675,"team2":"MADE Elite - 5th","team2Id":5679,"team1Score":"48","team2Score":"21","time":"2014-11-15T11:00:00"},{"id":8465,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 3","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1023,"team1":"Ravens - Etchison  8th","team1Id":5684,"team2":"Maryland 3D  8th","team2Id":5683,"team1Score":"41","team2Score":"48","time":"2014-11-15T11:00:00"},{"id":8445,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"HC Elite - Phillips  8th","team1Id":5685,"team2":"Maryland 3D Gold  8th","team2Id":5686,"team1Score":"80","team2Score":"34","time":"2014-11-15T12:00:00"},{"id":8440,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 3","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1023,"team1":"Force Attack 6th","team1Id":5681,"team2":"Savage Eagles  6th","team2Id":5678,"team1Score":"19","team2Score":"41","time":"2014-11-15T12:00:00"},{"id":8448,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"Glenwood  8th","team1Id":5688,"team2":"Maryland 3D Red 8th","team2Id":5680,"team1Score":"10","team2Score":"56","time":"2014-11-15T12:00:00"},{"id":8447,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 3","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1023,"team1":"HYCP Sharks - Red  5th","team1Id":5666,"team2":"MADE Elite -4th","team2Id":5667,"team1Score":"19","team2Score":"35","time":"2014-11-15T13:00:00"},{"id":8444,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"HC Elite - 7th","team1Id":5687,"team2":"Maryland 3D  8th","team2Id":5683,"team1Score":"24","team2Score":"39","time":"2014-11-15T13:00:00"},{"id":8439,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 4","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1024,"team1":"Columbia Ravens  6th","team1Id":5670,"team2":"MADE Elite  6th","team2Id":5673,"team1Score":"28","team2Score":"19","time":"2014-11-15T14:00:00"},{"id":8451,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"Force Attack 6th","team1Id":5681,"team2":"HC Elite White 6th","team2Id":5675,"team1Score":"19","team2Score":"54","time":"2014-11-15T14:00:00"},{"id":8456,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 3","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1023,"team1":"Elite Coalition  6th","team1Id":5677,"team2":"Savage Eagles  6th","team2Id":5678,"team1Score":"40","team2Score":"28","time":"2014-11-15T14:00:00"},{"id":8468,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"Baltimore Supreme  6th","team1Id":5672,"team2":"E-City Ballers - 7th","team2Id":5674,"team1Score":"22","team2Score":"23","time":"2014-11-15T14:00:00"},{"id":8452,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 4","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1024,"team1":"MD Playmakers Red - 8th","team1Id":5682,"team2":"HC Elite - Phillips  8th","team2Id":5685,"team1Score":"43","team2Score":"38","time":"2014-11-15T15:00:00"},{"id":8453,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"Ravens - Etchison  8th","team1Id":5684,"team2":"Maryland 3D Red 8th","team2Id":5680,"team1Score":"64","team2Score":"31","time":"2014-11-15T15:00:00"},{"id":8454,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 3","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1023,"team1":"Ravens  Cook  8th","team1Id":5689,"team2":"Maryland 3D Gold  8th","team2Id":5686,"team1Score":"56","team2Score":"35","time":"2014-11-15T15:00:00"},{"id":8455,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"Glenwood  8th","team1Id":5688,"team2":"HC Elite - 7th","team2Id":5687,"team1Score":"28","team2Score":"54","time":"2014-11-15T15:00:00"},{"id":8459,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 3","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1023,"team1":"Elite Coalition  6th","team1Id":5677,"team2":"MADE Elite - 5th","team2Id":5679,"team1Score":"61","team2Score":"31","time":"2014-11-15T16:00:00"},{"id":8461,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"Savage Eagles  6th","team1Id":5678,"team2":"HC Elite White 6th","team2Id":5675,"team1Score":"16","team2Score":"34","time":"2014-11-15T16:00:00"},{"id":8479,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 4","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1024,"team1":"Baltimore Supreme  6th","team1Id":5672,"team2":"Columbia Ravens  6th","team2Id":5670,"team1Score":"24","team2Score":"42","time":"2014-11-15T16:00:00"},{"id":8480,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"HC Elite Green 6th","team1Id":5671,"team2":"MADE Elite  6th","team2Id":5673,"team1Score":"52","team2Score":"18","time":"2014-11-15T16:00:00"},{"id":8462,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"Ravens  Cook  8th","team1Id":5689,"team2":"HC Elite - Phillips  8th","team2Id":5685,"team1Score":"41","team2Score":"29","time":"2014-11-15T17:00:00"},{"id":8464,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"Maryland 3D Gold  8th","team1Id":5686,"team2":"MD Playmakers Red - 8th","team2Id":5682,"team1Score":"27","team2Score":"65","time":"2014-11-15T17:00:00"},{"id":8449,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"Baltimore Supreme  6th","team1Id":5672,"team2":"MADE Elite  6th","team2Id":5673,"team1Score":"15","team2Score":"26","time":"2014-11-15T18:00:00"},{"id":8438,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 3","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1023,"team1":"E-City Ballers - 7th","team1Id":5674,"team2":"HC Elite Green 6th","team2Id":5671,"team1Score":"25","team2Score":"64","time":"2014-11-15T18:00:00"},{"id":8478,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"Reisterstown Wolfpack 5th","team1Id":5676,"team2":"Sharks - 4th","team2Id":5668,"team1Score":"40","team2Score":"12","time":"2014-11-16T08:00:00"},{"id":8483,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 3","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1023,"team1":"Maryland 3D  8th","team1Id":5683,"team2":"Maryland 3D Red 8th","team2Id":5680,"team1Score":"23","team2Score":"39","time":"2014-11-16T08:00:00"},{"id":8484,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"Ravens - Etchison  8th","team1Id":5684,"team2":"Glenwood  8th","team2Id":5688,"team1Score":"48","team2Score":"22","time":"2014-11-16T08:00:00"},{"id":8450,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"Columbia Ravens  6th","team1Id":5670,"team2":"E-City Ballers - 7th","team2Id":5674,"team1Score":"50","team2Score":"19","time":"2014-11-16T09:00:00"},{"id":8471,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"MADE Elite - 5th","team1Id":5679,"team2":"Force Attack 6th","team2Id":5681,"team1Score":"51","team2Score":"42","time":"2014-11-16T09:00:00"},{"id":8458,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 3","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1023,"team1":"Baltimore Supreme  6th","team1Id":5672,"team2":"HC Elite Green 6th","team2Id":5671,"team1Score":"37","team2Score":"59","time":"2014-11-16T09:00:00"},{"id":8457,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"Sharks - 4th","team1Id":5668,"team2":"MADE Elite -4th","team2Id":5667,"team1Score":"8","team2Score":"44","time":"2014-11-16T10:00:00"},{"id":8473,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"Ravens - Etchison  8th","team1Id":5684,"team2":"HC Elite - 7th","team2Id":5687,"team1Score":"35","team2Score":"36","time":"2014-11-16T10:00:00"},{"id":8467,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 3","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1023,"team1":"Reisterstown Wolfpack 5th","team1Id":5676,"team2":"HYCP Sharks - Red  5th","team2Id":5666,"team1Score":"21","team2Score":"36","time":"2014-11-16T10:00:00"},{"id":8482,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 3","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1023,"team1":"MADE Elite - 5th","team1Id":5679,"team2":"Savage Eagles  6th","team2Id":5678,"team1Score":"18","team2Score":"29","time":"2014-11-16T11:00:00"},{"id":8469,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"HC Elite Green 6th","team1Id":5671,"team2":"Columbia Ravens  6th","team2Id":5670,"team1Score":"50","team2Score":"26","time":"2014-11-16T11:00:00"},{"id":8470,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"Elite Coalition  6th","team1Id":5677,"team2":"HC Elite White 6th","team2Id":5675,"team1Score":"44","team2Score":"24","time":"2014-11-16T11:00:00"},{"id":8466,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"HCYP Sharks - Blue 5th","team1Id":5669,"team2":"MADE Elite -4th","team2Id":5667,"team1Score":"16","team2Score":"41","time":"2014-11-16T12:00:00"},{"id":8533,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"8th Red  1st Seed","team1Id":5698,"team2":"8th Red - 4th Seed","team2Id":5701,"team1Score":"42","team2Score":"49","time":"2014-11-16T12:00:00"},{"id":8534,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 3","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1023,"team1":"8th Red - 2nd Seed","team1Id":5699,"team2":"8th Red - 3rd Seed","team2Id":5700,"team1Score":"42","team2Score":"45","time":"2014-11-16T12:00:00"},{"id":8476,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"Maryland 3D  8th","team1Id":5683,"team2":"Glenwood  8th","team2Id":5688,"team1Score":"42","team2Score":"27","time":"2014-11-16T13:00:00"},{"id":8463,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"MADE Elite  6th","team1Id":5673,"team2":"E-City Ballers - 7th","team2Id":5674,"team1Score":"36","team2Score":"21","time":"2014-11-16T13:00:00"},{"id":8477,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"8th Red - Semi Final 1 winner","team1Id":5702,"team2":"8th Red - Semi Final 2 winner","team2Id":5703,"team1Score":"38","team2Score":"45","time":"2014-11-16T14:00:00"},{"id":8481,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 3","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1023,"team1":"Elite Coalition  6th","team1Id":5677,"team2":"Force Attack 6th","team2Id":5681,"team1Score":"71","team2Score":"29","time":"2014-11-16T14:00:00"},{"id":8535,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"HCYP Sharks - Blue 5th","team1Id":5669,"team2":"HYCP Sharks - Red  5th","team2Id":5666,"team1Score":"","team2Score":"","time":"2014-11-16T14:00:00"},{"id":8536,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"6-7th Grade 1st Seed","team1Id":5706,"team2":"6-7th Grade 2nd Seed","team2Id":5710,"team1Score":"","team2Score":"","time":"2014-11-16T15:00:00"},{"id":8537,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 3","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1023,"team1":"8th Grade White 1st Seed","team1Id":5707,"team2":"8th Grade White 2nd Seed","team2Id":5711,"team1Score":"","team2Score":"","time":"2014-11-16T15:00:00"},{"id":8538,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 1","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1021,"team1":"5th Grade 1st Seed","team1Id":5704,"team2":"5th Grade 2nd Seed","team2Id":5708,"team1Score":"","team2Score":"","time":"2014-11-16T16:00:00"},{"id":8539,"location":"Boys Latin School ct 2","locationUrl":"http://goo.gl/iZng1z","locationId":1022,"team1":"6th Grade 1st Seed","team1Id":5705,"team2":"6th Grade 2nd Seed","team2Id":5709,"team1Score":"","team2Score":"","time":"2014-11-16T16:00:00"}],"standings":[{"divisionName":" 5th","divisionStandings":[{"teamId":5667,"teamName":"MADE Elite -4th","wins":4,"losses":0,"winningPct":"1.000","pointsFor":151,"pointsAgainst":60,"pointsDiff":91},{"teamId":5666,"teamName":"HYCP Sharks - Red  5th","wins":2,"losses":1,"winningPct":".667","pointsFor":98,"pointsAgainst":65,"pointsDiff":33},{"teamId":5676,"teamName":"Reisterstown Wolfpack 5th","wins":2,"losses":2,"winningPct":".500","pointsFor":107,"pointsAgainst":98,"pointsDiff":9},{"teamId":5669,"teamName":"HCYP Sharks - Blue 5th","wins":1,"losses":2,"winningPct":".333","pointsFor":64,"pointsAgainst":80,"pointsDiff":-16},{"teamId":5668,"teamName":"Sharks - 4th","wins":0,"losses":4,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":39,"pointsAgainst":156,"pointsDiff":-117}]},{"divisionName":" 6-7th","divisionStandings":[{"teamId":5671,"teamName":"HC Elite Green 6th","wins":4,"losses":0,"winningPct":"1.000","pointsFor":225,"pointsAgainst":106,"pointsDiff":119},{"teamId":5670,"teamName":"Columbia Ravens  6th","wins":3,"losses":1,"winningPct":".750","pointsFor":146,"pointsAgainst":112,"pointsDiff":34},{"teamId":5673,"teamName":"MADE Elite  6th","wins":2,"losses":2,"winningPct":".500","pointsFor":99,"pointsAgainst":116,"pointsDiff":-17},{"teamId":5674,"teamName":"E-City Ballers - 7th","wins":1,"losses":3,"winningPct":".250","pointsFor":88,"pointsAgainst":172,"pointsDiff":-84},{"teamId":5672,"teamName":"Baltimore Supreme  6th","wins":0,"losses":4,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":98,"pointsAgainst":150,"pointsDiff":-52}]},{"divisionName":" 6th","divisionStandings":[{"teamId":5677,"teamName":"Elite Coalition  6th","wins":4,"losses":0,"winningPct":"1.000","pointsFor":216,"pointsAgainst":112,"pointsDiff":104},{"teamId":5675,"teamName":"HC Elite White 6th","wins":3,"losses":1,"winningPct":".750","pointsFor":160,"pointsAgainst":100,"pointsDiff":60},{"teamId":5678,"teamName":"Savage Eagles  6th","wins":2,"losses":2,"winningPct":".500","pointsFor":114,"pointsAgainst":111,"pointsDiff":3},{"teamId":5679,"teamName":"MADE Elite - 5th","wins":1,"losses":3,"winningPct":".250","pointsFor":121,"pointsAgainst":180,"pointsDiff":-59},{"teamId":5681,"teamName":"Force Attack 6th","wins":0,"losses":4,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":109,"pointsAgainst":217,"pointsDiff":-108}]},{"divisionName":"8th Red","divisionStandings":[{"teamId":5689,"teamName":"Ravens  Cook  8th","wins":3,"losses":0,"winningPct":"1.000","pointsFor":148,"pointsAgainst":100,"pointsDiff":48},{"teamId":5682,"teamName":"MD Playmakers Red - 8th","wins":2,"losses":1,"winningPct":".667","pointsFor":144,"pointsAgainst":116,"pointsDiff":28},{"teamId":5685,"teamName":"HC Elite - Phillips  8th","wins":1,"losses":2,"winningPct":".333","pointsFor":147,"pointsAgainst":118,"pointsDiff":29},{"teamId":5686,"teamName":"Maryland 3D Gold  8th","wins":0,"losses":3,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":96,"pointsAgainst":201,"pointsDiff":-105}]},{"divisionName":"8th White","divisionStandings":[{"teamId":5680,"teamName":"Maryland 3D Red 8th","wins":3,"losses":1,"winningPct":".750","pointsFor":168,"pointsAgainst":117,"pointsDiff":51},{"teamId":5683,"teamName":"Maryland 3D  8th","wins":3,"losses":1,"winningPct":".750","pointsFor":152,"pointsAgainst":131,"pointsDiff":21},{"teamId":5684,"teamName":"Ravens - Etchison  8th","wins":2,"losses":2,"winningPct":".500","pointsFor":188,"pointsAgainst":137,"pointsDiff":51},{"teamId":5687,"teamName":"HC Elite - 7th","wins":2,"losses":2,"winningPct":".500","pointsFor":134,"pointsAgainst":144,"pointsDiff":-10},{"teamId":5688,"teamName":"Glenwood  8th","wins":0,"losses":4,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":87,"pointsAgainst":200,"pointsDiff":-113}]},{"divisionName":"Sunday Championships","divisionStandings":[{"teamId":5701,"teamName":"8th Red - 4th Seed","wins":1,"losses":0,"winningPct":"1.000","pointsFor":49,"pointsAgainst":42,"pointsDiff":7},{"teamId":5703,"teamName":"8th Red - Semi Final 2 winner","wins":1,"losses":0,"winningPct":"1.000","pointsFor":45,"pointsAgainst":38,"pointsDiff":7},{"teamId":5700,"teamName":"8th Red - 3rd Seed","wins":1,"losses":0,"winningPct":"1.000","pointsFor":45,"pointsAgainst":42,"pointsDiff":3},{"teamId":5704,"teamName":"5th Grade 1st Seed","wins":0,"losses":0,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":0,"pointsAgainst":0,"pointsDiff":0},{"teamId":5708,"teamName":"5th Grade 2nd Seed","wins":0,"losses":0,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":0,"pointsAgainst":0,"pointsDiff":0},{"teamId":5706,"teamName":"6-7th Grade 1st Seed","wins":0,"losses":0,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":0,"pointsAgainst":0,"pointsDiff":0},{"teamId":5710,"teamName":"6-7th Grade 2nd Seed","wins":0,"losses":0,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":0,"pointsAgainst":0,"pointsDiff":0},{"teamId":5705,"teamName":"6th Grade 1st Seed","wins":0,"losses":0,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":0,"pointsAgainst":0,"pointsDiff":0},{"teamId":5709,"teamName":"6th Grade 2nd Seed","wins":0,"losses":0,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":0,"pointsAgainst":0,"pointsDiff":0},{"teamId":5707,"teamName":"8th Grade White 1st Seed","wins":0,"losses":0,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":0,"pointsAgainst":0,"pointsDiff":0},{"teamId":5711,"teamName":"8th Grade White 2nd Seed","wins":0,"losses":0,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":0,"pointsAgainst":0,"pointsDiff":0},{"teamId":5699,"teamName":"8th Red - 2nd Seed","wins":0,"losses":1,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":42,"pointsAgainst":45,"pointsDiff":-3},{"teamId":5698,"teamName":"8th Red  1st Seed","wins":0,"losses":1,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":42,"pointsAgainst":49,"pointsDiff":-7},{"teamId":5702,"teamName":"8th Red - Semi Final 1 winner","wins":0,"losses":1,"winningPct":".000","pointsFor":38,"pointsAgainst":45,"pointsDiff":-7}]}]}
```

and your leagues.html page will look like this

```
<ion-view ng-controller="LeaguesCtrl as vm">
  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <div class="list">
        <a class="item item-icon-right" ng-repeat="league in leagues.locations" ng-click="vm.selectLeague(league.id)">
        {{league.name}}
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory "></i>
        </a>

    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Reply back if having any queries

Comment: I don't want to inject more dependencies because he didn't do that at the tutorial.. the code is pretty the same but I don't knw where is the problem by having no results at the console

Answer (score 0):

The Error was from the coding of ionic when I remove  from the code it works:

```
<ion-view ng-controller="leaguesCtrl">
    <ion-content class="has-header">
        <h1>Leagues</h1>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```